# Add table of methods in Sphinx documentation of a class

Tags: python, python-sphinx

How can I automatically add a table with the list of the methods for a given class using Sphinx? Something like in the scikit-learn documentation ([example](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html)):

[image]

Thanks very much.

Edit: Thank you very much mzjn! Thanks to `autosummary`, there is now a table with the description of the methods. However the layout is not very pretty:

[image]

It looks better on the API file:

[image]

There are dots when the list of parameters is too long.

Comment: The table is generated by the `autosummary` directive. See https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/autosummary.html#directive-autosummary.

Comment: Thank you very much! Now I have the summary table, but the list of parameters is a bit too long and collapses with the description of the method. It looks like this:
https://pyts.readthedocs.io/en/update_doc_theme/generated/pyts.classification.KNeighborsClassifier.html

while it looks better in the `api` file:
https://pyts.readthedocs.io/en/update_doc_theme/api.html

Any idea how I can fix this?

Comment: If there are problems with the exact layout of the documentation when you use autosummary, I think you should either rephrase this question or post a new question.

Comment: I don't see any problem here: https://pyts.readthedocs.io/en/update_doc_theme/generated/pyts.classification.KNeighborsClassifier.html

Comment: Maybe it depends on the web browser... I am using Safari. Would you mind telling me which web browser you are using?

Comment: No problem on Chrome indeed. Seems like not a sphinx issue then, I will mark this question as answered. Thank you very much once again.

Comment: Latest Firefox (69.0) also works fine.